# SqlQuery<T> equivalent in EF Core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, ado.net, .net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am migrating from ASP.NET Framwork 4.7 to Asp .NET Core 3.1 and I am really stuck in the following:

I have a SQL query:

```
string Query=" 
SELECT I.Id,I.Combokod,I.S_Omr,I.Date,M.Price,M.Name,M.Dmedel,M.Year,M.Miles 
    FROM dbo.Itemannounces AS I  
    INNER JOIN dbo.MotorDBs AS M ON I.MotorDBs_Id=M.Id  where M.MotorID=1" ;
```

My customized class:

```
public class Fordonlista
        {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte Combokod { get; set; }
        public byte Affarsform { get; set; }
        public byte Model { get; set; }
        public byte Dmedel { get; set; }
        public short Year { get; set; }
        public int Miles { get; set; }
        public short S_Omr { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Lan { get; set; }
        public string Kommun { get; set; }
        public byte Typ { get; set; }
        }
```

In order to retreive the data I use:

```
var result = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Fordonlista>(Query).ToList();
```

The question is how to get the result in EF Core? If the EF Core is light weight why even move from Framwork to a downgraded EF Core at all?

Comment: See EF Core documentation for [Raw Sql Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). Event though the sample query you've posted can easily be produced with LINQ, thus avoiding the raw Sql drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new EF Core 3 method `FromSqlRaw()` for this.
In your example that would then be

```
string Query=" 
    SELECT I.Id,I.Combokod,I.S_Omr,I.Date,M.Price,M.Name,M.Dmedel,M.Year,M.Miles 
    FROM dbo.Itemannounces AS I  
    INNER JOIN dbo.MotorDBs AS M ON I.MotorDBs_Id=M.Id
    where M.MotorID=1" ;
var result = Context.Fordonlista.FromSqlRaw(Query);
```

But even better would be to pass a parameter as following:

```
int motorId = 1; //or passed in from other variable
var result = Context.Fordonlista.FromSqlInterpolated(
    $"SELECT I.Id,I.Combokod,I.S_Omr,I.Date,M.Price,M.Name,M.Dmedel,M.Year,M.Miles
      FROM dbo.Itemannounces AS I  
      INNER JOIN dbo.MotorDBs AS M ON I.MotorDBs_Id=M.Id
      WHERE M.MotorID={motorId}";
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the result entity is part of your database context (e.g. one of the tables) doesn't it? Is there a mapping variant that just maps back from non store types from the results in the stored procedure?